# SOLVE 415 error (unsupported mediaType) in angularjs for below code usnig spring

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using **AngularJs** with **Spring** and rest , when I change `@RequestBody` to `@ModelAttribute` the code works but data inserted in database is `null`.

So help me solving this issue . I am using **MySQL** database.

**This is my app.js**

```
(function() {
    var formapp = angular.module('formapp', []);
    formapp.controller('formController', function($scope, $http) 
        $scope.regForm = {
            "firstName" : "hii",
            "lastName" : "bye"
        };
        $scope.submit = function() {

            var url = "";
            var method = "";

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'insert.html',
                data : angular.toJson($scope.regForm),
                headers : {
                    'Accept':'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf8'
                }

            }).then(success());
        }
        function success() {
            clearFormData();
        }
        // Clear the form
        function clearFormData() {
            $scope.regForm.firstName = "";
            $scope.regForm.lastName = "";
        };
    });
})();
```

**This is my controller**

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.dao.RegistrationDAO;
import com.vo.RegistrationVO;

@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index.html" })
    public String load() {
        return "angularForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert.html", method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void insert(@RequestBody RegistrationVO registrationVO) {
        System.out.println("------");
        this.registrationDAO.insert(registrationVO);
    }
}
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Can you change the attribute of @RequestMapping as like `@RequestMapping(value = "/insert.html", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`) ?

Comment: Already did nothing works

Comment: {\"firstName\":\"hii\",\"lastName\":\"bye\"} is this a proper json format??? If not how to change it???

Comment: I think you should remove `'Accept':'application/json'` from request or you can add `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in you controller. And you can try to remove `;charset=utf8` from `Content-Type` of request headers.

Comment: Still same error , should i write @ModelAttribute??

Comment: Can you return something like `String` as `@ResponseBody` from controller. Header would be `headers : {
                    'Accept':'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }`

Comment: try to pass directly regForm object like this `data : $scope.regForm,`

Comment: Still the same error